# Best way to play video from Url in iOS

Tags: ios

I am playing a video from Url, It is playing but very slow. I am using my mobile data.

Her is the code I play the video:

```
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_selectedVideo.videoLink]];
    self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

    videoLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
    videoLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    [self.avPlayer play];
```

It is really slow and takes long time to start. Is there any way to make it faster?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try mpmovieplayer to play video.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =
        [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame 
[myView addSubview: player.view];
// ...
[player play];
```

Comment: Even if I use MPMoviePlayerController still have the same speed.

Comment: Use multipart then. It will divide the video into parts and will download each part in different thread.